# Is it possible make requests to the server from another network

Tags: azure, networking, server, ip, vpn

To elaborate more on the title, (that I know is confussing, I would appretiate if someone make it better)

I need to connect a PC that is off the office to the server that is being hosted on azure,
but only the calls being made from the office IP are trusted by the server.

I need to be able to connect to it from of the premisses, on my laptop.

Is there any way to do this,  with a vpn or something like that?

Answer (score 2):

I think the easies way to achieve your goal without exposing VM to public Internet is [Point-to-site VPN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-point-to-site-resource-manager-portal):

1. You add and configure a VPN gateway on Azure Virtual Network where VM is placed
2. You allocate a private address space to Point-to-site connections and authorize its IP range at VM level (Security Group, Firewall or any other method that you use to protect the traffic in Azure)
3. You install a VPN client on your laptop and connect to VM with it's private IP address